# Java Object Creation Error 3

Tags: java, object

I am a Java newbie where I am learning Java through tutorial document from website. I am following its example but get error during Java object creation example.

**Here is the code:**

```
public class Puppy {
    public Puppy(String name) {
        //This constructor has one parameter, name.
        System.out.println("Passed name is:" + name);
    }
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        //Following statement would create an object myPuppy
        Puppy myPuppy =newPuppy("tommy);
    }
}
```

**The idea is to show this output:**

> Passed name is:tommy

**Here is the error when I compile the code:**

```
sgxxgunawcm1:Code Set gunawc$ javac Puppy.java 
Puppy.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
Puppy myPuppy = newPuppy("tommy");
symbol:   method newPuppy(String)
location: class Puppy
1 error
```

Can someone help me to get rid of this? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed space between `new` and `Puppy`, Try this:

```
Puppy myPuppy = new Puppy("tommy);
-------------------^
```

Instead of:

```
Puppy myPuppy =newPuppy("tommy);
```

Answer (score 1):

`new` is the Java keyword that tells it to instantiate/create a new object. Your syntax should be:

```
Puppy myPuppy = new Puppy("tommy");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yours error is this:

```
 Puppy myPuppy =newPuppy("tommy);
```

the correct way is:

```
 Puppy myPuppy = new Puppy("tommy");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Puppy` creation line should be:

```
Puppy myPuppy = new Puppy("tommy");
```

The [`new`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) keyword is responsible for creating a new object and allocating memory. Watch out for typographical errors like that; remember that key words such as `new` are not arbitrary; the Java compile needs to be able to find and read those specific operators, otherwise it doesn't know what to do.

Additionally, the error "cannot find symbol" essentially means the Java compiler searched for, and was unable to find, a method or variable with that name (`newPuppy` in this case) with your scope. Some more info can be found [here](http://cs-people.bu.edu/dgs/courses/cs111/assignments/errors.html).